# Rename filenames and remove gaps in the order with batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm wondering how to rename my screenshots in my screenshot folder to their number order.
I sometimes remove some screenshots, but then the game fills in the gaps which causes a chronological issue.

It looks like this:

```
screenshot0000.jpg
screenshot0002.jpg
screenshot0005.jpg
```

And I would like to rename them to this:

```
screenshot0000.jpg
screenshot0001.jpg
screenshot0002.jpg
```

I hope I don't ask too much here but I'm sure someone would like to give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    pushd "x:\where\theFiles\are" && (
        set "count=10000"
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on "screenshot*.jpg"') do (
            echo ren "%%~fa" "screenshot!count:~-4!.jpg"
            set /a count+=1
        )
        popd
    )
```

This will output to console the rename commands. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.